# Why does my off screen rendering Canvas3D not work?

Tags: java, 3d, bufferedimage, java-3d, canvas3d

I've been trying to make off screen rendering to work, using [Java3D 1.5.2](https://java3d.dev.java.net/). In my [source code](http://pastie.org/597573) I've been trying to attach an extended `Canvas3D` that will do off-screen rendering to `SimpleUniverse`, but doing so will break the render:

```
62.  // FOR SOME REASON THIS BREAKS RENDERING
63.  universe.getViewer().getView().addCanvas3D(canvas);
```

The full source code is a bit too large to paste on StackOverflow so I made it available via Pastie over [here](http://pastie.org/597573).

Line 63 has been commented out and has the ordinary Canvas3D do on-screen rendering. It will render a cube and display this in a `JFrame`. However if you remove the comment the off-screen render will cause the on-screen one from not rendering. Also the off-screen rendering will return a "big black nothing" `BufferedImage`.

I'd like to know how to make the off screen rendering work, i.e. render the scene of a rotated cube to a buffered image. I've been looking at the Java3D provided example code for off-screen rendering and they do it as this as well (with the exception that they use the `Raster` object to render the off screen buffer back to an on-screen window).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be the physical dimension of the Screen3D that is wrong. The value is supposed to be size of the physical screen in meters. You can test with:

```
screen3D.setPhysicalScreenWidth(0.0254/90.0 * destWidth);
screen3D.setPhysicalScreenHeight(0.0254/90.0 * destHeight);
```

The values are from the top of the Screen3D javadoc. The problematic line worked together with the above code, at least for me :)

Setting the wrong physical dimension may also change the aspect ratio of the rendered image.

Comment: Sweet, it works! Btw do you what exactly I need to do in order to make the program exit itself. It is still running even when the rendering is done as if some resource is still running and I can't put my finger on where it is doing that. (I'm calling universe.cleanup() but that doesn't seem to be enough). I'll accept the answer after that.

Comment: I would try .dispose() all frames. If that doesn't work, then call System.exit(0), which will kill the jvm. If you need the jvm to continue running, then more research is needed :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured out on using System.exit(0), but I don't need anything more elegant than that so it's okay. Thanks.